# How to link my external style sheet?

Tags: css

```
<html>    
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"> - external stylesheet

        <div class = "idiot" href = "css.css">Purchase!</div>   
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>

    <style type="text/css">
        .idiot { cursor:pointer; }
        .idiot:link { color: gray; }
        .idiot:visited { color: red; }
        .idiot:hover { color: black; }
        .idiot:active { color: blue; }  
    </style>
</html>
```

Under here is what is written in the external stylesheet-

```
body { background-color:black; }
```

So, I click on the link, but nothing pops up, and nothing even happens at all.

Comment: You cannot set a `href` attribute for a div. Either try `<a href="css.css"><div class = "idiot">Purchase!</div></a>` or `<div class = "idiot" onclick="javascript:window.location'">Purchase!</div>`

Comment: Your file is probably named wrong or not in the same folder. Are there any error messages in the browser dev console?

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with your code. The head is reserved for `meta`-tags, `link`s, the `title` etc. You can not define elements (like `div`) in there.

You correctly linked your stylesheet with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
```

Be sure to check if the path inside `href` is correct and `css.css` is indeed in the same folder as your HTML-file.

All styling should be done inside the `css.css` from now on. It gets applied automatically so you don't have to and are not allowed to use `href` inside a `div`. You also can not click anything right now because that would require something like `<a href="dest">Link</a>`.

Here is a snippet:

```css
body { 
  background-color: green; 
}

.idiot {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  color: black;
}

.idiot:link {
  background-color: gray;
}

.idiot:visited {
  background-color: red;
}

.idiot:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.idiot:active {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>title of the website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="idiot">
      Purchase!
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Be sure to put all CSS code into your stylesheet. I added some styling to your div so you can see the difference properly. I also added `background-color` to make the difference more drastic since `color` only styles the text.